# Cross domain access issue with http://whateverorigin.org/

Tags: javascript, jquery, https, jsonp, cross-domain-policy

Hi I have used the http://whateverorigin.org/ origin to get content from other domain and display it on my domain.

The issue is my page uses `https://` but (http://whateverorigin.org/) supports only `http://`.

If I change the url to `https://whateverorigin.org/` the iFrame never loads the content.

So how do I overcome this problem, Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

The code:

```
var url = 'https://www.otherdomain.com/001003227.htm';
$.getJSON('https://whateverorigin.org/get?url=' + 
           encodeURIComponent(url) + '&callback=?', function(data){
```

Comment: @user2813355: What is the exact error you are getting in console??

Comment: I am not getting any error in console but in browser I see Loading… and nothing gets loaded.

Answer (score 1):

DO NOT DO IT. Http Content within a HTTPS page is inherently insecure. Point. This is why IE shows a warning. Getting rid of the warning is a stupid hogwash approach.

Instead, a HTTPS page should only have HTTPS content. Make sure the content can be loaded via HTTPS, too, and reference it via https if the page is loaded via https. For external content this will mean loading and caching the elements locally so that they are available via https - sure. No way around that, sadly.

Answer (score 1):

According to an [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/ripper234/Whatever-Origin/issues/18) you can do the following:

> I recommend using the following path if HTTPS is an requirement:
>
> `https://whateverorigin.herokuapp.com/get?url=...`
>
> Trying to access the main page with HTTPS will not work due to how the certificate is setup.

I've tested this on my own site and it works.